# Knockout.js ViewModel change callback?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to implement an auto-save feature in a Knockout.js app.

Is there a way to assign a callback for whenever a ViewModel changes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at Ryan Niemeyer's smart, dirty flag at http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to create a dependantObservable that depends on everything in your ViewModel - I assume someone will post an answer better than this one that contains code showing it.

(I would prefer if there was a built in "any change" callback, but as far as I can tell there is not.)