# How to create dirty flag functionality

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to create dirty flag functionality using knockout. I want to enable the save button only if something has changed. My view and my view model is exactly same as example found on knockout js tutorial Loading and Saving data. [Link to tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving)

I am following fiddle example posted by Ryan [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dtpfv/)

I am not able to understand where to declare below code which he has declared in view model.

```
 this.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(this);
```

If i take example from knockout tutorial the link which i posted above and i tried like below

```
function Task(data) {
this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);
this.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(this);
```

}

Binded my view like below

```
<button data-bind="click: saveOperation , enable: isDirty" >Save</button>
```

It gives me error as unable to parse binding isDirty is not defined.

I am not sure how to go on implementing this.

Comment: I haven't used this project, but I looked at it: https://github.com/romanych/ko.editables seems to be what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout.js ViewModel change callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775038/knockout-js-viewmodel-change-callback)

Comment: I have found fiddle based on knockout tutorial. I modified it and added dirtyflag in Task. I am trying to use KoLite here. I get error on Cancel button that dirtyFlag is not defined http://jsfiddle.net/ashreva/bGsRH/234/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

1. You are defining the `dirtyFlag` on your `Task` function. But you are checking it on the view bound to the viewModel instance.
2. You have to define the dirty flag **after** you loaded the data or you have to call `dirtyFlag().reset()`.
3. `isDirty` is a computed. You have to call it with parenthesis.

The view model looks like:

```
function TaskListViewModel() {
    // Data

    function Task(data) {
    this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
    this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);

}

    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
    self.incompleteTasks = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.tasks(), function(task) { return !task.isDone() && !task._destroy });
    });

    this.dirtyFlag = new ko.DirtyFlag(this.isDone);

    // Operations
    self.addTask = function() {
        self.tasks.push(new Task({ title: this.newTaskText() }));
        self.newTaskText("");
    };
    self.removeTask = function(task) { self.tasks.destroy(task) };
    self.save = function() {
        $.ajax("/echo/json/", {
            data: {
                json: ko.toJSON({
                    tasks: this.tasks
                })
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                self.dirtyFlag().reset();
                alert(ko.toJSON(result))
            }
        });
    };

     //Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
    $.ajax("/echo/json/", {
        data: {
            json: ko.toJSON(fakeData)
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var mappedTasks = $.map(data, function(item) {
                return new Task(item);
            });

            self.tasks(mappedTasks);

            self.dirtyFlag().reset();
        }
    });                               
}
```

The binding for the cancel button:

```
<button data-bind="enable: dirtyFlag().isDirty()">Cancel</button>
```

And the working fiddle (a fork of yours) can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/delixfe/ENZsG/6/

Comment: First of all tons of thanks for putting efforts. But fiddle you provided is not working. I tried to change some data in text box but button is not enabling. Why is it so?

Comment: JsFiddle had some problems saving. I lost all my changes and had to start anew. It should work now: http://jsfiddle.net/delixfe/ENZsG/6/

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks and tons and tons of thanks you little genius. Tomorrow i will try on my actual code and get back to you.

Comment: In my actual viewmodel i am still getting error 
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot call method 'isDirty' of undefined;
Bindings value: visible: showSave, click: saveOperation , enable: dirtyFlag().isDirty()

Comment: if i bind to my view like this  enable: dirtyFlag.isDirty. Removing paranthesis then i am not getting error which i mentioned in above comment. But now i get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reset' of undefined"  What is this now

Comment: Please help me. I am still struggling

Comment: Great news. Its working now. But i have few question before i close this question. I binded my view like this enable: dirtyFlag.isDirty(). you did it like enable: dirtyFlag().isDirty()
Why is this different behaviour. Also i did self.dirtyFlag.reset(); and you did as self.dirtyFlag().reset(); Why did it work when i removed paranthesis around dirtyFlag. Please explain i really need to understand this. Also i declare dirty flag as self.dirtyFlag = new ko.DirtyFlag(self.versionDataByProduct); instead of using "this" keyword

Comment: It really depends on the dirty tracker version you are using. The implementations you referred to try to avoid to send the data twice (the data as JSON and again the change tracking JSON). Therefore they use closures or properties of functions to hide that. It is hard to tell you more without seeing your code.

Comment: i am using kolite version which you used in fiddle. So i am still confused

Comment: Can you tell me how to make flag dirty forcefully. Please answer. Many many thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 4):

The dirty flag for knockout is already implement in the small library `koLite` - https://github.com/CodeSeven/kolite .

Or here is an example of creating it: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: Can we chat? Its difficult explaining here

Comment: I have found fiddle based on knockout tutorial. I modified it and added dirtyflag in Task. I am trying to use KoLite here. I get error on Cancel button that dirtyFlag is not defined
http://jsfiddle.net/ashreva/bGsRH/234/

Answer (score 0):

There is also the ko.editables plugin: https://github.com/romanych/ko.editables

```
var user = {
    FirstName: ko.observable('Some'),
    LastName: ko.observable('Person'),
    Address: {
        Country: ko.observable('USA'),
        City: ko.observable('Washington')
    }
};
ko.editable(user);

user.beginEdit();
user.FirstName('MyName');
user.hasChanges();          // returns `true`
user.commit();
user.hasChanges();          // returns `false`
user.Address.Country('Ukraine');
user.hasChanges();          // returns `true`
user.rollback();
user.Address.Country();     // returns 'USA'
```

Comment: Will you be able to make it work on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ashreva/bGsRH/234/

Comment: I have now tried almost all techniques but none is working on my model. I have provided link to my fiddle in above comment. If you can show me there then i will be really thankful to you. I have toiled past 4 days without luck

Comment: I was, but I could not finish in time. I think that the script your are using might have a bug. I try to have a look this evening or tomorrow ...

Comment: i really wish you could make it to work very soon. Thanks buddy

Comment: I have created a new answer which fixes your problems with koLite. I have left this one because it shows an alternative.