# Multiple checkbox using jquery and knockout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I want to have multiple checkbox implemented in table or list like this image below.

[image]

How can i achieve it using Jquery and knockout. Knockout will bind data to checkboxes.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: Data will have language name , code and ischecked column

Comment: I don't wish to be rude, but you should at least be trying to write some code in your question, if only to show an attempt to get this to work. I think the general principle here is that people will help you with problems, not do your work for you. Sorry to be harsh, but I see that someone has already marked this question down, so I thought I'd give you an explanation for why that might have happened.

Comment: @PaulManzotti I agree with you. My fault. But i need some guideline on exactly what to use to make it look it like that. I never meant that i want whole code to be written. Can you give me some tips or ideas on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

A simple foreach over your data, with the code for each table row bound to the individual properties in each data item, one property per table cell. You can use the [checked binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) to determine whether a checkbox needs to be checked.

Comment: Is there example of displaying multiple checkboxes  in table?

Comment: Erm, you just have one input type=checkbox per row, set the value to the code, if you want. Give them the same name if you want one variable posted when you submit the form, or else when you want to submit something, use jQuery to loop through the checkboxes and pull out all the codes that have been checked.

Comment: ok will do and let you know. Now if i try something and face issue then should i ask new question

Comment: No, I'd update this question with your code, as it will be part of the same question.

Comment: Many thanks Paul. Not sure if i should accept answer or keep question open. +1 for your quick reply

Comment: will you able to help me on my question? Cant say how much thankful i can be. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567269/how-to-create-dirty-flag-functionality