# Knockout JS Creating a Dirty flag

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an ASP.NET MVC project where I'm converting my Model of type IEnumerable into a JS string and storing in a hidden input.  Then I'm parsing that string at applyBindings time to a viewModel object which a data-bind="foreach: rows" on a  element binds to.  This system is part of an MVC framework internally developed where I work and needs to be built as an easily re-usable system.  The prime design goal is to get consuming code to just build a .NET ViewModel with attributes which drive the layout.  I'm trying to prevent the developer from needing to write the JS viewmodels to match.

The JS I have in a sample project for initialising the binding is as follows:

```
var thingy = function(rowData){
    rows = ko.mapping.fromJS(rowData);
};


var el1 = $("#someGrid > tbody");
if (el1.length > 0) {
    var dataStr = el1.attr("data-ko-data");
    var data = JSON.parse(dataStr);
    var vm = thingy(data);

    ko.applyBindings(vm, el1[0]);

}
```

My .NET POCO looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }

    public Tuple<string, Type>[] Properties()
    {
        var propInfos = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        var ret = propInfos.Select(i => new Tuple<string, Type>(i.Name, i.PropertyType));
        return ret.ToArray();

    }
}
```

Each table on the form has a "save changes" button which is supposed to scan the table's viewmodel and post the rows marked IsDirty = true back to an MVC Action for saving.

```
$(".gridSaveButton").click(function () {
    var theUrl = $(this).attr("data-saveurl");
    var theTable = $(this).siblings("table"); 

    var dirtyRows = [];

    var theBody = theTable.children("tbody");
    var trs = theBody.children("tr");
    trs.each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var modelForRow = ko.dataFor(row[0]);
        if(modelForRow.IsDirty)
        {
            dirtyRows.push(modelForRow);
        }

    });

    var theData = ko.toJSON(dirtyRows);
    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: theData,
        success: function (status) {
            alert("Success: " + status.Success);
        },
        error: function (request, status, theError) {
            alert(theError);
        }
    });

});
```

So the above works as expected.  What I'm having trouble with is working out how to set the IsDirty value to true for a specific row when ANY of the properties on the object are modified.  Every example I've found on line so far deals with setting IsDirty as a ko.computed based on certain other ko.observables, but I can't do this directly because the user would have to then write an explicit JS viewmodel for each type.

I tried to create a custom binding but neither the init nor update gets called so I'm a little lost on that, and for that matter if it's even the right approach.

Has anyone had any experience with this sort of thing and know how I can simply respond to ANY other variable on an object when the declaration of the object is implicit?

--
Steve

Comment: Its probably overkill for what you are trying to do, but I would suggest that you have a look at [breezejs](http://www.breezejs.com/).  It will keep a track of your objects dirty status plus create the model client side from the models on the server when used with ASP Net web API and either Entity Framework or nhibernate.

Comment: Also this [blog post about creating a smart IsDirty flag](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html) might help also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create dirty flag functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567269/how-to-create-dirty-flag-functionality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've used this sample as a base and got it working nicely.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7Nsuh/

That is a modified version to suit my needs where I'm using ko.mapping.fromJS, although from Ryan's original versionhttp://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dtpfv/ there's a dirtyItems list on the viewModel.  With the modified approach does anyone know how to add the calculated dirtyItems to koRowMapping ?

I tried this but the binding fails and I'm not even sure if the approach is correct anyway:

```
var koRowMapping = {
    rows: {
        create: function (options) {
            return createRow(options.data);
        }
    },
    dirtyItems: ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.rows, function(row) {
            return row.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
        });
    }, this)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Roighto!!

I got there in the end.

So it's just as per the original examples  by Ryan:

```
var koRowMapping = {
    rows: {
        create: function (options) {
            return createRow(options.data);
        }
    }

};

var createRow = function (row) {
    var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(row);
    result.dirtyFlag = ko.dirtyFlag(result);
    return result;
}

ko.dirtyFlag = function (root, isInitiallyDirty) {
    var result = function () { },
        _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root)),
        _isInitiallyDirty = ko.observable(isInitiallyDirty);

    result.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
        return _isInitiallyDirty() || _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
    });

    result.reset = function () {
        _initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
        _isInitiallyDirty(false);
    };

    return result;
};
```

And then put the dirtyItems and global dirty flag on the viewmodel:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var people = '{"rows":[{"FirstName":"Steve","LastName":"O"},{"FirstName":"Someone","LastName":"Else"}]}';

    var vm = ko.mapping.fromJSON(people, koRowMapping, {});
    vm.dirtyItems = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.rows(), function(item) {
            return item.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
        });
    }, vm);

    vm.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.dirtyItems().length > 0;
    }, vm);


    var el = $("#theTable");
    ko.applyBindings(vm, el[0]);
}
```

Fabulous!!!!